# Close server-side chat connections before unload in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, session

On my website, I have built a chatroom with support for multiple rooms. When a user joins the room, a session is placed into the database so that if they try to join the room again in another browser window, they are locked out.

It works like this

```
1. Join the chatroom page
2. Connect to chatroom #main
If the user has a session in the database for #main
--- Block user from joining
else
--- Load chatroom
```

When the chatroom is closed client side or the user terminates there connection with the /quit command, all of their sessions are deleted, and this works fine.

**However**
There is a possibility that users will just close the browser window rather than terminating their connection. The problem with this is that their session will stay in the database, meaning when they try to connect to the room, they are blocked.

I'm using this code onbeforeunload to try and prevent that

```
function disconnect() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/remove-chat-sessions.php?global",
            async: false
        });
};
```

This is also the function called when the user types the /quit command

**The problem**
The problem with this is that when I reload the page, 5 times out of 10 the sessions have not been taken out of the database, as if the ajax request failed or the page reloaded before it could finish. This means that when I go back into the chatroom, the database still thinks that I am connected, and blocks me from entering the chatroom

Is there a better way to make sure that this AJAX call will load and if not, is there a better alternative than storing user sessions in an online database?

**Edit:**
The reason users are blocked from joining rooms more than once is because messages you post do not appear to you when the chatroom updates for new messages. They are appended to the chatroom box when you post them. This means that if users could be in the same chatroom over multiple windows, they would not be able to see the comments that they posted across all of the windows.

Comment: Perhaps instead of blocking them on join with a new session you should invalidate the old session and use the new.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn, the reason they are blocked is because messages you post do not appear to you in the chatroom. they appear when you post them. this means that if users could be in the same chatroom over multiple windows, they would not be able to see the comments that they posted across all of the windows.

Comment: So lets say you have a poll that checks for new messages every few seconds. When it does it's poll, have it check if the session in the table matches the session for the request. If they don't match then send back a message saying "You have been disconnected because you are logged into another window" and stop the polling. Then only set the session in the table when they join/leave a room, not on  poll.

Comment: After reading the comments and the edit, I think that you basically have a problem somewhere and try to solve it in a completely different way. While IMHO my answer is correct for the original question, I'd recommend you to reword the whole question to address your particular problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation you could add some sort of polling. Basically, you request with javascript a page every X time. That page adds the user session to the database. Then there's a script executing every Y time, where Y > X, that cleans old sessions.

The script that is called every X time

```
...
// DB call (do as you like)
$All = fetch_all_recent();
foreach ($All as $Session)
  {
  if ($Session['time'] < time() - $y)
    {
    delete_session($Session['id']);
    }
  }
```

The script that javascript is calling every X time

```
...
delete_old_session($User->id);
add_user_session($User->id, $Chat->id, time());
```

The main disadvantage of this method is the increment in requests, something Apache is not so used to (for large request number). There are two non-exclusive alternatives for this, which involve access to the server, are:

1. Use [nginx server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx). I have no experience in this but I've read it supports many more connections than Apache.
2. Use some modern form of persistent connection, like [socket.io](http://socket.io/). However, it uses node.js, which can be good or bad, depending on your business.

Comment: In my experience, nginx handles static pages/content better than apache, but apache handles dynamic content such as php better. Either way though, it is just an opinion and not really needed to answer the question.

Comment: This helped me to go onto what I needed to do, thanks.